# Java Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException runtime error

Tags: java, function, methods, runtime-error, program-entry-point

I have been making a simple java program as a homework assignment for school. When I added a method to retrieve a 2D array from a .txt file this error appeared. The program does not show any errors when compiling. I am a new programmer so please go through anything added or changed thoroughly. Please feel free to give me further tips and advice other than the question at hand.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class simpleAI2
{

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      int count = 0;
      String[][] array = new String [20][4];
      simpleAI2.getArrayData(array);
      String leaveQ;
      int rep = 1;

      do
      {
         int countTwo = 0;
         boolean flag = false;
         Scanner scanName = new Scanner (System.in);
         Scanner scanSport = new Scanner (System.in);
         Scanner leave = new Scanner (System.in);


         System.out.println("My name is A.I.S.C.M.B.T. What is your name?");
         array[count][1] = scanName.nextLine ();
         System.out.println("Hi "+array[count][1]+"! What's your favourite sport?");
         array[count][2] = scanSport.nextLine ();
         String sport = array[count][2];

         for(int x = 1;x<rep;x++)
         {
            if(!array[countTwo][2].equals(null) && array[countTwo][2].equals(array[count][2]))
               {
               flag = true;
               x = 28;
               }

            else
               {
               flag = false;
               }

            countTwo ++;
         }


         countTwo --;

         if(flag == true)
            {
            System.out.println("I know "+array[countTwo][2]+". It is "+array[countTwo][3]+". My friend "+array[countTwo][1]+" knows it");
            }

         if(flag == false)
            {
            System.out.println("I don't know "+array[count][2]+". I only know robot boxing. Robots hit each other until one malfunctions. What is this alien sport you speak of?");
            array[count][3] = scanSport.nextLine ();
            }

         System.out.println("Go again? Type no to leave me :(");
         leaveQ = leave.nextLine ();

         rep ++;

         count ++;

         if(leaveQ.equals("no"));
            {
            simpleAI2.Save(array);
            }

      }while (!leaveQ.equals("no"));

   }



   public static void Save(String [][] array){

      try {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<array[x].length; y++){
               writer.write(String.valueOf(array[x][y]));
            }
            writer.println(); 
         }

         writer.flush();  
         writer.close();        



      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
         {      
         e.printStackTrace();
         }


   }

   public static void getArrayData(String [][] array){

      try {
         Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("arrayData.txt"));

         for(int i=0; i<array.length;  i++){
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
               array[i][j]=scan2.next(); 


            }
         }


      } 

      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
         }    

   }
}
```

Comment: do you run it via command line or IDE?

Comment: @erhun I use jGrasp so IDE

Comment: Can we see the stacktrace?

Comment: @KacyRaye I'm afraid I don't know what that is :/ I'm very new to java and programming in general

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `Scanner` function [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) when there is nothing left to read, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.
Change your code to the following:

```
public static void getArrayData(String [][] array)
{
    try 
    {
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("arrayData.txt"));

        for(int i=0; i<array.length;  i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if ( ! scan2.hasNext() )  //if there's nothing left to read
                    return;               //exit the function

                array[i][j]=scan2.next(); 
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there are no errors. The program itself isn't working now. If the program 'learns' about football, exits then restarts it should still know it. But it didn't

Comment: @userX I won't solve all your bugs, but I can give you tips.  It seems like it's possible your entire array will not be filled up with input from the file.  That said, String arrays start out with `null` as their default value, so you should check that the element your saving to the file in your `save()` function is not writing null values (unless you want that behavior).  
Step through your program and use print statements to debug.  If the output looks perfect, then you may be misunderstanding how a function from the external libraries work.  Read their descriptions in the java API online.

Comment: When I open the text file it says null a lot. I'm assuming this means it is writing null values. Why is this not what I want and how can I get it to not write null values?

Comment: The method does start. I'm not sure that the 'try' does